# Is linear ordering of singleton set simply an empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Basically while studying ordinal arithmetic I have stumbled multiple times across claims like saying that membership relation is well ordering on natural number 1 and things like that until I realized that number 1 has only one element,namely an empty set,and no other elements to compare that element to

Basically the whole question is in the title but I wanted to give some background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by linear order you mean total, irreflexive and transitive order. Then yes. If by linear order you mean total, reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive, then the linear order of a singleton is just its square.

Comment: I admire your ever-presence on this site.And once again thanks for your answer

Comment: Heavy lies the crown.